# make all author names in bibliography (chicago style) bold and make the bibliography title "reference" not bold

Tags: bold, biblatex-chicago

I am using the following code for my latex project:

```
        \usepackage[authordate, maxcitenames=3,
        backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
        \addbibresource{BibFile.bib}
```

and

```
    \printbibliography[
title={REFERENCES}
]
```

I want to all the author names in the bibliography bold. And at the same time, the title word "Referece" of the bibliography not bold. I searched a lot, but failed to find a solution, can someone help? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those are two completely orthogonal questions. I suggest you ask separate questions about them (see also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864).

Comment: For the bibliography heading the solution will also depend on your document class and other modifications you are applying to headings. `\printbibliography` typesets its heading with a normal `\section*` or `\chapter*` command that is formatted like all similar commands in the document. If you want the bibliography heading to behave differently from normal chapter headings, additional work is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting of the bibliography heading will depend on the document class (and other things), which you haven't shown us. So I will try to answer the question about bold names and encourage you to ask a new question about the bibliography heading with a compilable example document (an MWE: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)).

You can get bold names easily with the new name wrapper commands (added in `biblatex` v3.12 from 2018-10-30)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, maxcitenames=3, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,
  nussbaum,westfahl:space,moraux,pines}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bold names.]

Comment: Thanks so much, it is very helpful.